# Disable CodeRush Refactor Popup Menu

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, coderush

I'm trying to figure out how to disable the CodeRush (v14.1.5.0) Refactor menu that pops up in Visual Studio 2013 (the ellipses). I do want the refactoring capabilities of CodeRush, but I'd rather just access it with a right click or the Ctrl + ` hotkey. Unfortunately, the popup gets in my way when I'm doing a lot of mouse work and I find myself clicking it on accident. Attached is a screenshot of the popup I'm talking about. The ellipsis, specifically, is what gets in the way.

I've done several searches on SO and Google with no luck. Thanks in advance!

[image: CodeRush Refactor Popup]

Comment: Did you me the "What heppened popup" ?

Comment: @hdoghmen Sorry, it's not the "What Happened Popup" I'm describing. I've added a screenshot to help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress -> CodeRush -> Options

Core -> Features

and then uncheck **Enable "What heppened" popup**